# Как открыть вайл XLS который защищен паролем

Tags: php, phpexcel

Подскажите как открыть файл .xls который защищен паролем. Пароль на сам файл имеется. Для доступа к файлу использую PHPExcel.

$imputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($imputFile);

$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($imputFileType);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($imputFile);

Comment: phpExcel давно не поддерживается. Используйте phpspreadsheet. Ну и вот вариант - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941725/open-xlsx-file-that-protected-by-a-password-with-phpspreadsheet

Comment: @n.osennij попробывал сделать по примеру в ссылке, высыпает ошибка Your requested sheet index: -1 is out of bounds. The actual number of sheets is 0.

Comment: если не путаю, то перед чтением нужно выбрать лист. Попробуйте явно выбрать лист с помощью $spreadsheet->getSheet(0); - https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/worksheets/