# Как открыть книгу XLSX защищенную паролем PHP?

Tags: php, excel

Подскажите как отрыть книгу excel защищенную паролем?
В интернете не смог найти информацию в основном предлагается задать пароль книги.
Пытаюсь открыть вот так

```
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

    $imputFile = Yii::getAlias('@backend/web/uploads/') . "m.xlsx";

    $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($imputFile);

    $spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
    $spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
    $spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("922104");

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    echo $sheet->getCell('C10')->getValue() . "\n";
```

Если снять пароль с книжки то все читается и выводится на экран, стоит его поставить получаю ошибку: 
**Your requested sheet index: -1 is out of bounds. The actual number of sheets is 0.**

Comment: Документацию читали? https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#setting-security-on-a-spreadsheet - и если да, то точно пароль на книге, а не на документе?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как открыть вайл XLS который защищен паролем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914952/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-xls-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

Только вручную!

1. Создайте резервную копию файла excel.
2. Измените расширение файла с .xlsx на .zip.
3. Теперь извлеките все содержимое zip-файла.

Найдите xml целевого листа. Вы найдете его в каталоге `xl -> worksheets`.

4. Откройте xml-файл целевого листа в редакторе xml.
5. Найдите  "sheetProtection" в этом XML-файле и удалите его.
6. Сохраните отредактированный файл xml, и замените его на старый xml-файл в zip-файлах.
7. Измените расширение с .zip на .xlsx.

Всё!